# send two values in a link to another page

Tags: c#, html, razor, hyperlink, query-string

i need to use two values in my links.

here is my current code:

```
<a href='<%# String.Format("products.aspx?cat={n}/,mybrand={x}", Eval("116"), Eval("Samsung"))%>'></a>
```

well ! is not working. how can i send these two values ("116" & "samsung") with 
my link ?

note:
i'm using a page that shows all of my products. but i need to filter contents by category and brand. so i need to send these two values from every link to that page.

Comment: @JafferWilson
no. i'm using .net

Answer (score 0):

found it !

link should be like this:

```
<a href="products.aspx?cat=116&brand=Samsung">Product</a>
```

and in second page in page_load:

```
Textbox.Text = Request.QueryString("cat") 
Textbox.Text =Request.QueryString("brand")
```